# VBA, CATIA Macro break loop

Tags: vba, catia

[When I click the `Next` button on the form I would like to get the next part on the Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnSzk.png) 
I have a `for` loop that goes through Product Tree and reads `PartName` in variable `oForm.txtPartName`. On `oForm` there is a button `Next` and what it's supposed to do is break the `for` loop and jump on the next part on the tree. What code should I put into the `Next` button to get the job done?

```vb
For i = 1 To oProducts.Count
       
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oPartDoc = oProducts.Item(i).ReferenceProduct.Parent
    
    Set oPart = oPartDoc.part
    
        If CInt(Mid(oPart.Name, 26, 3)) > 100 Then

        oForm1.txtPartName = oPart.Name
        
        oForm1.Show

        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: Welcome to the board.  There really isn't enough here to answer your question. Please review   [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It looks like the button is on a form inside excel, rather than some kind of HTML button on a web site.  You already know what oProducts.Count is, right.  Can't you just use that number to move the process forward.  Something like Application.Run Activesheet.Shapes(1).OnAction or CommandButtonNext_Click.  I think that should do it.